# Implementing oauth2 in browser for login

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I have a question that is how to implement oauth2 in laravel for login in browser.I have implemented login using web in laravel but i dont know how to implement it using oauth2 passport.Can anyone explain please...

Answer (score 0):

Oauth is a stateless authentication process so you'll need to be attaching a token to each request as a header (or cookie or query parameter).

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer <token value>'
```

There are several different means for obtaining a token, which you use is entirely dependent on how a user will be interacting with your app/api.

I'd thoroughly read through the [Passport Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport) before writing any code and get a firm understanding of the various Oauth flows.